# How to get data from JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

When I have a normal array and multidimensional array in PHP and I return them like this

```
$data['normalArray'] = $array;
$data['multiArray'] = $multiArray;

echo json_encode($data);
```

How can I access them in jQuery? I tried using $.each but no results

/edit Some extra info I'm using ajax to get the objects, and the normal one works now but not sure how to do the multidimensional array

```
success: function (result) 
                $.each(result.normalArray, function (i, item) {
                    console.log(item.key);
                });
            }
```

Comment: Hi Bart! JSON means Javascript Object Notation. All objects in javascript is a JSON. An jQuery is a javascript library... So, to access to the fields of a JSON in javascript, you can access by its keys. If you do not know the keys you can ask for them by var keys = Object.keys(json) that will return you an array with all the keys. After that you can perform a keys.forEach(...)

Answer (score 2):

You've to parse the JSON String to object using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

[$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery is designed to loop through the DOM elements. You can also loop/iterate through Array of elements.
 But first you need to parse the JSON string returned from PHP using **JSON.parse(JSON_STRING)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $.getJSON('url',function(r){
           for($i=0;$i<=r.length;$i++){
               // your code with object r 
            }
        });
```